# Black screen on boot up no bios

Tags: windows, hardware-failure

I have a Windows system and when I turn it on everything runs and turns on but the monitor stays black. No BIOS shown or anything. Ideas?

This is also a brand new system. No more then a year old running an i5.

Could it be powersupply?

Answer (score 3):

**COMMON EASY ISSUE:** Did you recently move the computer and plug the monitor into the on-board video plug when you actually have a video card installed.

**MONITOR:** Try replacing the monitor first with another one you have laying around.

**VIDEO CARD:** Take the video card out and reseat it.  If that doesn't work then remove and try onboard video or a different video card all together

**MEMORY:** If your memory is not seated properly (not in), is damaged, or even absent altogether, this can cause a black screen.  If you have more than one memory module then try one at a time to see if either is defective.

**POWER USPPLY:** Black screen on startup with an amber flashing light.  A flashing amber light along with your black screen on startup can mean that you are not getting enough power to the motherboard, the power supply is dead or a pin or shorted port may be present

**OTHER:** Leaving a bootable USB flash drive connected to your computer can cause a black screen.